# xgboost predict method returns the same predicted value for all rows

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I've created an xgboost classifier in Python:

train is a pandas dataframe with 100k rows and 50 features as columns.
target is a pandas series

```
xgb_classifier = xgb.XGBClassifier(nthread=-1, max_depth=3, silent=0, 
                                   objective='reg:linear', n_estimators=100)
xgb_classifier = xgb_classifier.fit(train, target)

predictions = xgb_classifier.predict(test)
```

However, after training, when I use this classifier to predict values the entire results array is the same number. Any idea why this would be happening?

Data clarification:
~50 numerical features with a numerical target

I've also tried [`RandomForestRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) from sklearn with the same data and it does give realistic predictions. Perhaps a legitimate bug in the xgboost implementation?

Comment: What does your data look like?  What is the "same number" that the model is returning?

Comment: something like -0.1236788. It is in the range of expected results, but different rows should have different values predicted and this number fills up the entire predictions array ~ 1000 rows

Comment: can you share the code how you call the train function and how you fill the training matrix ? Are there positive and negative examples in the training set ?

Comment: I've added the code. Yes there are both positive and negative values in the training set.

Answer (score 6):

This question has received several responses including on this thread as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054887/xgboost-predictor-in-r-predicts-the-same-value-for-all-rows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824429/xgboost-prediction-always-returning-the-same-value-why).

I was having a similar issue with both XGBoost and LGBM.  For me, the solution was to increase the size of the training dataset.

I was training on a local machine using a random sample (~0.5%) of a large sparse dataset (200,000 rows and 7000 columns) because I did not have enough local memory for the algorithm.  It turned out that for me, the array of predicted values was just an array of the average values of the target variable.  This suggests to me that the model may have been underfitting.  One solution to an underfitting model is to train your model on more data, so I tried my analysis on a machine with more memory and the issue was resolved:  my prediction array was no longer an array of average target values.  On the other hand, the issue could simply have been that the slice of predicted values I was looking at were predicted from training data with very little information (e.g. 0's and nan's).  For training data with very little information, it seems reasonable to predict the average value of the target feature.

None of the other suggested solutions I came across were helpful for me.  To summarize some of the suggested solutions included:
1) check if gamma is too high
2) make sure your target labels are not included in your training dataset
3) max_depth may be too small.

Comment: In my case, I had a null value in the y variable; I just ussed .fillna(0) and it worked @Blane

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons for the same is that you're providing a high penalty through parameter gamma. Compare the mean value of your training response variable and check if the prediction is close to this. If yes then the model is restricting too much on the prediction to keep train-rmse and val-rmse as close as possible. Your prediction is the simplest with higher value of gamma. So you'll get the simplest model prediction like mean of training set as prediction or naive prediction.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase (significantly) `min_child_weight` in XGBoost or `min_data_in_leaf` in LightGBM:

```
min_data_in_leaf    oof_rmse
20000               0.052998
2000                0.053001
200                 0.053002
20                  0.053015
2                   0.054261
```

Actually, it may be a case of overfitting masking as underfitting. It happens for instance for zero-inflated targets in case of insurance claims frequency models. One solution would be to increase the representation/coverage of rare target levels (e.g. non-zero insurance claims) in each tree leaf, by increasing the hyperparameter controlling minimum leaf size to some rather large values, such as those specified in the example above.

Comment: This was a great clue; but in fact for me reducing min_child_weight stopped the overfitting (class averaging?)... in fact the prediction still dreadful, but at least it is now predicting different values now!

Answer (score 0):

Won't the max_depth =3 too smaller, try to get it bigger,the default value is 7 if i remember it correctly. and set silent to be 1, then you can monitor what's the error each epochs

Answer (score 0):

You need to post a reproducible example for any real investigation. It's entirely likely that your response target is highly unbalanced and that your training data is not super predictive, thus you always (or almost always) get one class predicted. Have you looked at the predicted probabilities at all to see if there is any variance? Is it just an issue of not using the proper cut-off for classification labels?

Since you said that a RF gave reasonable predictions it would useful to see your training parameters for that. At a glance, it's curious why you're using a regression objective function in your xgboost call though -- that could easily be why you are seeing such poor performance. Trying changing your objective to: `'binary:logistic`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check there are no `inf` values in your target.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and managed to fix it. The problem was I was training on `tree_method='gpu_hist'` which gave all the same predictions. If I set `tree_method='auto'` it works properly but wayy longer runtimes. So then if I set `tree_method='gpu_hist'` along with `base_score=0` it worked. I think `base_score` should be about the mean of your predicted variable.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried all solutions on this page, but none worked.

As I was grouping time series, certain frequencies created gaps in data.
I solved this issue by filling all NaN's.

Answer (score -2):

Probably the hyper-parameters you use cause errors. Try using default values. In my case, this problem was solved by removing `subsample` and `min_child_weight` hyper-parameters from params.