# XGBoost predictor in R predicts the same value for all rows

Tags: python, r, xgboost, kaggle

I looked into the the post on the same thing in Python, but I want a solution in R.
I'm working on the Titanic dataset from Kaggle, and it looks like this:

```
    'data.frame':   891 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ PassengerId: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Survived   : num  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ Pclass     : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 ...
 $ Age        : num  22 38 26 35 35 ...
 $ SibSp      : int  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 1 ...
 $ Parch      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 ...
 $ Fare       : num  7.25 71.28 7.92 53.1 8.05 ...
 $ Child      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ Embarked.C : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ Embarked.Q : num  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Embarked.S : num  1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ Sex.female : num  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ Sex.male   : num  1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...
```

This is after I used dummy variables. My test set:

```
'data.frame':   418 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ PassengerId: int  892 893 894 895 896 897 898 899 900 901 ...
 $ Pclass     : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 ...
 $ Age        : num  34.5 47 62 27 22 14 30 26 18 21 ...
 $ SibSp      : int  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 2 ...
 $ Parch      : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ Fare       : num  7.83 7 9.69 8.66 12.29 ...
 $ Child      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Embarked.C : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Embarked.Q : num  1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Embarked.S : num  0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ Sex.female : num  0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ Sex.male   : num  1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...
```

I ran xgboost using the following code:

```
> param <- list("objective" = "multi:softprob",
    +               "max.depth" = 25)
    > xgb = xgboost(param, data = trmat, label = y, nround = 7)
    [0] train-rmse:0.350336
    [1] train-rmse:0.245470
    [2] train-rmse:0.171994
    [3] train-rmse:0.120511
    [4] train-rmse:0.084439
    [5] train-rmse:0.059164
    [6] train-rmse:0.041455
```

trmat is:

```
trmat = data.matrix(train)
```

and temat is:

```
temat = data.matrix(test)
```

and y is the survived variable:

```
y = train$Survived
```

But wen i run the predict function:

```
> x = predict(xgb, newdata = temat)
> x[1:10]
 [1] 0.9584613 0.9584613 0.9584613 0.9584613 0.9584613 0.9584613 0.9584613
 [8] 0.9584613 0.9584613 0.9584613
```

All probabilities are being predicted to be the same. In the python question, someone said increasing max.depth would work, but it didn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the `Survived` variable in your test set in order to use xgboost, since this is the variable you want to predict.

```
trmat = data.matrix(train[, colnames(train) != "Survived"])
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to answer, I have faced the same problem when I first used xgboost. Removing the "Survived" column from train set should solve your problem. If we have the column in train set which we use for label in xgboost then the algorithm ends up predicting all probabilities to be same.

Comment: I appreciate the contribution, but is this any different from the answer provided above by jlesuffleur?

Comment: The column should be removed from train set. Jlesuffleur mentioned it as test set though the code she gave was for train set.