# XGBoost prediction always returning the same value - why?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using SageMaker's built in XGBoost algorithm with the following training and validation sets:

https://files.fm/u/pm7n8zcm

When running the prediction model that comes out of the training with the above datasets always produces the exact same result.

Is there something obvious in the training or validation datasets that could explain this behavior?

Here is an example code snippet where I'm setting the Hyperparameters:

```
{
                    {"max_depth", "1000"},
                    {"eta", "0.001"},
                    {"min_child_weight", "10"},
                    {"subsample", "0.7"},
                    {"silent", "0"},
                    {"objective", "reg:linear"},
                    {"num_round", "50"}
                }
```

And here is the source code: https://github.com/paulfryer/continuous-training/blob/master/ContinuousTraining/StateMachine/Retrain.cs#L326

It's not clear to me what hyper parameters might need to be adjusted.

This screenshot shows that I'm getting a result with 8 indexes:
[image]

But when I add the 11th one, it fails. This leads me to believe that I have to train the model with zero indexes instead of removing them. So I'll try that next.
[image]
Update: retraining with zero values included doesn't seem to help. I'm still getting the same value every time. I noticed i can't send more than 10 values to the prediction endpoint or it will return an error: "Unable to evaluate payload provided". So at this point using the libsvm format has only added more problems.

Comment: You must be more specific with code samples. ML models are not returning the same value unless you did something wrong in the way (hyper-parameters, serving or calling the model...)

Comment: @Guy I added the hyperparameters I've been testing with above. I've trying different values but seem to keep getting the same behavior. I don't even have intuition as to what specific parameters I should be focusing in on.

Comment: The other thing I noticed is all the examples I've used from SageMaker us 'libsvm' as the data type for XGBoost training, but I'm trying to use 'csv'.

Comment: @PaulFryer I've looked at your data and it is very **sparsed**. Therefor it is recommended you'll work with 'libsvm'. worry not, as xgboost knows how to handle 'libsvm' format :)

Comment: @EranMoshe Interesting, I didn't realize one format works better with sparse data than another. I will work on a libsvm implementation and test with the hypterparameters you suggested and will followup with results. Thanks for your help here.

Comment: @PaulFryer I don't think it works better. Its just a better way to store the data as instead of having 100000000 NaNs (0) you'll have a much cleaner data file. It might work faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xgboost predict method returns the same predicted value for all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470477/xgboost-predict-method-returns-the-same-predicted-value-for-all-rows)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few things wrong there.

1. using `{"num_round", "50"}` with such a small ETA `{"eta", "0.001"}` will give you nothing.
2. `{"max_depth", "1000"}` - 1000 is insane! (default value is 6)

Suggesting:

```
    {"max_depth", "6"},
    {"eta", "0.05"},
    {"min_child_weight", "3"},
    {"subsample", "0.8"},
    {"silent", "0"},
    {"objective", "reg:linear"},
    {"num_round", "200"}
```

Comment: I converted to libsvm and posted training, validation, and single test data here: https://files.fm/u/wnpexcmm#_ When I send the test data to the Inference Endpoint, I get the following error from SageMaker Runtime service: "Unable to evaluate payload provided". Do you see any issues with the test.txt file example I provided in the link here?

Comment: @PaulFryer Can't see any problem with it no. post the training process. Did the error minimize with each iteration? Do you now have different predictions to different events?

Comment: Training validation RMSE started at 0.48213, after 200 iterations it was down to 0.116052

Comment: I'm still getting the same value with any values I send in. Also if I send more than 10 values it will blow up saying "unable to evaluate the payload provided". How do I increase the number of allowed values? I need to send it hundreds.

Comment: Try to take a real "event" from your training like the one in row 2 (which his target value is 0.00184). And another event from row 16 (where the target value is -0.00679) and predict those. and show me exactly how you ask your model about them

Answer (score -1):

As I was grouping time series, certain frequencies created gaps in data.
I solved this issue by filling all NaN's.